# ListView with CursorAdapter slow refresh

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I am using a `ListActivity` which displays a `ListView` with the help of a `CursorAdapter` and a `ContentProvider`.

The list contains more than 1.000 items, so the initial load takes a while.
If the user selects an item, another activity is called via `startActivityForResult()`.
The user can edit the item, changes are stored in database.

Back in `ListActivity` with `onActivityResult()`: The cursor is reloaded with `getAdapter().changeCursor()` and the view is refreshed with `getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`

Is this the right way? Because the refresh takes 1-2 seconds and is very slow!

Comment: Are you using a `CursorLoader`?

Comment: Many things can cause a slow app, your queries are my first guess. Anyway the [Android SDK comes with Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html#RunTestEclipse) to help break down and identify the slowest elements of your app

Comment: @almisoft : If you have created your own `Adapter` by extending one of the standard Android adapters, you can call your own `getView(...)` method to quickly update a single list item. Search here on StackOverflow for something like "Update single list item"

Comment: @zapl No, I don't. But that is a good advice, because at the moment the query blocks my app

Comment: @Sam: Yes, the query is the slowest element, it takes about 1,5 seconds on a SGSII with 8193 items. But it is a normal and simple SELECT, without subqueries. On my Nexus 7 the query is done in 10ms, but only with 100 items.

Comment: @Squonk: the list refresh is not the slow element, only the requery. If I only refresh the view, the cursor is the same as before...

Answer (score 0):

Using AsynTask and run a backgroundTask and you can use RecyclerView instead if ListView